# How to derive gradient descent flow of curve evolution?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, gradient-descent

I was confused with two different ways to derive the gradient flow of curve evolution.
Given curve $C(p)$, where $p$ is an arbitrary parameter of curve, and there is a relationship between it and arc length parameter, $ds = ||C_p||dp$.
Given an energy function
$$E(C)=\int_C ds$$

There are two methods to derive gradient descent flow.

(1)
If I want to get the gradient descent flow $\nabla_C E$, below is the derivation.
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}E(C)=\langle\nabla_C E, C_t\rangle = \int_C \nabla_C E\cdot C_t ds=\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_Cds$$
replace $ds$ with $||C_p||dp$, it becomes
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}E(C)=\int_0^1\dfrac{d}{dt}||C_p||dp = \int_0^1\dfrac{C_{pt}\cdot C_p}{||C_p||}dp$$
Since $p$ and $t$ are independent, $C_{pt}$=$C_{tp}$. With relationship of $ds = ||C_p||dp$,
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}E(C)=\int_C C_{ts}\cdot C_sds$$
Take integral by parts,
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}E(C)=\int_C C_t\cdot (-C_{ss})ds$$
Therefore, $\nabla_C E=-C_{ss}$.

(2)
Another way is that we know $\nabla_C E$ equals to Euler-Lagrange criterion. So How about directly computing it from $E(C)=\int_0^1 ||C_p||dp$ ? And what is the difference between these two ways?.

Method (2) seems much simplier.